# Shopping cart is not clearing on the cart page

Tags: magento2, cart

After I updated from Magento version 2.2.3 to 2.2.6 the shopping cart stopped clearing after I click "Clear Shopping Cart" on the cart page.

After I click the button, the page reloads but everything remains the same.

I am using Ultimo theme but I have checked and it doesn't overwrite this behavior anyhow.

What could be the possible issue and where should I start my investigation from?

Comment: I am having same issue with Magento 2.2.6 and Latest version of Ultimo theme. Did you find a solution? This is exception I am seeing in log file. main.CRITICAL: Requested product doesn't exist {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Requested product doesn't exist at /home/web/site/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:271)

Comment: @Haya Check phagento answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've also encountered this issue and I've found out that in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml` `~line 27`, Magento Team seems missed to put a dot for the '**action**' classname. It's a small mistake that creates a big problem. Hopefully this will be fixed in 2.2.7

So from

```
action.clear
```

It should be

```
.action.clear
```

*Note: Please don't edit the file in

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml

directly.*

Comment: I just checked one of my 2.2.7 websites and this issue is still present. I don't like the button personally (its hidden w/ css) but I don't think they've yet realized they need to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

When a user clicks on **Clear Shopping Cart**  button then you have to check below:

- On  click on this button the
  `http://{Example.com}/checkout/cart/updatePost/`  should hit.
- This URL must hit via POST request.

  This post request must have form_key and update_cart_action, and  `update_cart_action` value should be `empty_cart`

*FORM DATA should like when to click on **Clear Shopping Cart***

```
form_key: 4VQpuhYHzS9dOY3P
cart[15][qty]: 1
cart[17][qty]: 1
update_cart_action: empty_cart
```

Where 15,17 are cart item id.

If those are available or exist then the exception is not happening.
You check error, check the exception log or   changes

[`$this->messageManager->addException($exception, __('We can\'t update the shopping cart.'));`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdatePost.php#L60)

to

```
$this->messageManager->addError($exception->getMessage()
```

Comment: update_cart_action parameter is missing. Is it related to JavaScript?

Comment: @Amit Bera please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Cart Page >> Clear Shopping Cart button should have alert to the users if they want to clear or not.

Here I am overriding form.phtml in my theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Namespace/yourthemename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml
```

> > form.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**  @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid */
?>
<?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
<form action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart":
              {"validationURL" : "/checkout/cart/updateItemQty"}
          }'
          class="form form-cart">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="cart table-wrapper<?= $mergedCells == 2 ? ' detailed' : '' ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-top toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-top"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <table id="shopping-cart-table"
               class="cart items data table"
               data-mage-init='{"shoppingCart":{"emptyCartButton": ".action.clear",
               "updateCartActionContainer": "#update_cart_action_container"}}'>
            <caption role="heading" aria-level="2" class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Cart Items') ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col item" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Item') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col price" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Price') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col qty" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></th>
                    <th class="col subtotal" scope="col"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Subtotal') ?></span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </table>
        <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="cart-products-toolbar cart-products-toolbar-bottom toolbar" data-attribute="cart-products-toolbar-bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
    <div class="cart main actions">
        <?php if ($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
            <a class="action continue"
               href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>"
               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Continue Shopping')) ?>">
                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Continue Shopping') ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button"
                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')); ?>"
                class="action clear" id="cp-empty_cart_button">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Clear Shopping Cart'); ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-empty=""
                value="empty_cart"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action clear" id="empty_cart_button" style="display: none;">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="submit"
                name="update_cart_action"
                data-cart-item-update=""
                value="update_qty"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Update Shopping Cart')) ?>"
                class="action update">
            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="update_cart_action_container" data-cart-item-update=""/>
    </div>
</form>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.order.actions') ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after') ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ], function ($, alertt, confirmation) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.cp-action-accept').parents('aside').addClass('confirm');
            $('#cp-empty_cart_button').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                confirmation({
                    title: '',
                    content: 'Are you sure to remove products from cart ?',
                    actions: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            window.location.href = '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost'); ?>';
                        },
                        cancel: function () {
                        }
                    },
                    buttons: [{
                        text: $.mage.__('OK'),
                        class: 'action secondary cp-action-accept',
                        /**
                         * Click handler.
                         */
                        click: function (event) {
                            this.closeModal(event, true);
                            $('#empty_cart_button').trigger('click');
                        }
                    },
                        {
                            text: $.mage.__('Cancel'),
                            class: 'action secondary action-dismiss',
                            /**
                             * Click handler.
                             */
                            click: function (event) {
                                this.closeModal(event);
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Output will be like this :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is 'update_cart_action' Parameter is not sending because Mageno developers added `'Magento_Checkout/js/action/update-shopping-cart'` js function for validation. They Submit the form in this file. So the submit button value param is not sending. Add the hidden field with submit button name in

```
Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/form.phtml


<input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_hidden" name="update_cart_action" value="">
```

And assign the value of submit button using onClick event to the hidden field

```
$('.update-cart-action').click(function(){
     $('#update_cart_action_hidden').val($(this).val());
});
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Its a default bug in Magento2 version :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18475

To resolve this issue you need to override the file

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/form.phtml`

into your theme

`app/design/frontend/{PackgageName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/from.phtml`

and change the `line number 27` from `action.clear` to `.action.clear`

Answer (score -1):

**It's default bug.**

Here I am overriding form.phtml in my theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Namespace/yourthemename/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml
```

Two Changes required

1) At line no 17 :

> /checkout/cart/updateItemQty

to

> updateItemQty

2)  At line no 27 :

> action.clear

```
to
```

> .action.clear

Comment: do you really need to redo the answer done above? :D